# Right click with cocos2d-html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cocos2d-html5

I use cocos2d-html5 2.2.2, onMouseUp function detects left and middle click, but right clicks have no effect. I use Firefox 27. Is there something I should enable to support right clicks ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I understand it, you can not capture a "right click" in a web browser application. Okay, technically solutions to that effect exist but they are not standardized, may not work on all browsers and most importantly are detrimental to the user's browsing experience. Since websites that do capture right-clicks are so obnoxious some browsers offered to prevent this behavior altogether so right-click always brings up the context menu.

Comment: links: http://giannopoulos.net/2012/02/26/right-click-menus-in-html5/
and: http://css.dzone.com/articles/all-mouse-events-javascript